# Manipulating a sum and showing it has an upper bound

Tags: complex-analysis, summation, sums-of-squares

Let $x_1, \ldots ,x_n$ and $y_1, \ldots , y_n$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$ be complex numbers such that 
$$\left| \sum_{k=1}^n x_k y_k \right| \leq 1. $$
Further I know that 
$$ \sum_{k = 1}^n |x_k|^2 \leq 1.$$
My question is: does 
$ \sum_{k = 1}^n |y_k|^2 \leq 1. $ also hold? And assuming $ \sum_{k = 1}^n |x_k|^2 \leq 1 $ and $ \sum_{k = 1}^n |y_k|^2 \leq 1 $ hold does $\left| \sum_{k=1}^n x_k y_k \right| \leq 1 $ hold? How do I proof this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider $x_1=1$, $x_2=0$ and $y_1=0$, $y_2=\lambda$. Then
$$
\left|\sum_{k=1}^2x_ky_k\right|=0\le1
$$
and
$$
\sum_{k=1}^2x_k^2=1
$$
However,
$$
\sum_{k=1}^2y_k^2=\lambda^2
$$
which can be as large as we want.

---

The second part follows from the [Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality).

Comment: Nice example! But how do I show that this holds for all x_i and y_i?

Comment: One counterexample is enough to show that something is not true. If $\lambda\le1$, then we *do* have that $\sum\limits_{k=1}^2y_k^2\le1$. So there are times when the inequality will be true and times when it will be false. The fact that there are cases in which it is false, makes the statement that the inequality is always true, false.